# How to correctly handle the Spring Kafka Producer failures of sending messages?

Tags: java, http, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a Spring Kafka application that receives an HTTP request and sends its payload into the Kafka topic. I want to anticipate the following unsuccessful scenario:

1. Initially, the application works properly: it receives HTTP requests and publishes data in Kafka.
2. At a certain point, sending to Kafka becomes impossible due to any reasons.
3. The application receives new HTTP request, tries to send data in Kafka and fails with that.

In this case, the app cannot retry publishing in Kafka infinitely, because it should return the HTTP response: whether it is successful or not.

**What I've done**

To consider that, I've configured the [`delivery.timeout.ms`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#delivery-timeout-ms) property for the producer. And implemented sending to the Kafka in this way:

```java
  ... 
  @Value("${spring.kafka.producer.properties[delivery.timeout.ms]}")
  private Long deliveryTimeoutMs;

  public void sendMessage(String data) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
      kafkaTemplate.send(topic, data).get(deliveryTimeoutMs, MILLISECONDS);

    } catch (CancellationException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
      String msg = String.format(UNABLE_TO_PUBLISH_DATA_IN_KAFKA, topic, data);
      log.error(msg, e);
      throw new KafkaProducerServiceException(msg, e);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      String msg = String.format(UNABLE_TO_PUBLISH_DATA_IN_KAFKA, topic, data);
      log.error(msg, e);
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

So the application tries to send data in Kafka, waits the same period of time as it specified in `delivery.timeout.ms` property and in case of failure it returns 500 HTTP response.

**The problem**
When I try to do the following:

1. Run my application and run Kafka in Docker.
2. Initially make some successful publishes.
3. Pause Kafka container.
4. Send another one HTTP request to the app (and receive the 500 response after `delivery.timeout.ms`)
5. Run Kafka container again.

Then I see that **data from the failed HTTP request was published in Kafka anyway** – even after the `delivery.timeout.ms`. And even after more time (like 30 minutes). But the sender system already received the 500 response. If it retries this failed request, **data will be duplicated in the Kafka topic**. How can I avoid this?

P.S. Please let me know if you see any errors in my train of thoughts.

Thank you!

Comment: A couple of observations: 1) Whenever you catch `InterruptedException` you should execute `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` - otherwise you "eat" the interrupt and any downstream interruptible operations will block (possibly forever). 2) You are using the same timeout for the future completion - you might get a `TimeoutException` there, when the underlying send was successful; you need to add a buffer to the future wait time. (I am not suggesting that will solve your problem - I am just pointing out the possible timing issue).

Comment: @GaryRussell, thank you for your answer! Can I ask you a couple of questions regarding your observations? 

1) In my example, I catch `InterruptedException` just to print logs and then rethrow it again, hoping that Spring will manage it under the hood. Does your advice mean that it will not happen, and I should interrupt the current thread by myself?
2) I've got your point, thanks! What amount of buffer time would you recommend?

Comment: 1) Sorry, my mistake, I didn’t notice the rethrow. I often see code that just logs, or throws a RuntimeException with it as a cause, which causes the interrupt to be lost. It has got to a point where not seeing a reinterrupt stands out to me. 2) It’s hard to say, depends on CPU utilization, garbage collection pauses etc., but in most cases 50-100ms should be enough, but I often use more than that, just in case.

Comment: 1) That's okay, I heard it's a common problem :) 2) Thank you for advice! As I see, in my case even when I add several seconds as a buffer, get() method throws an exception after delivery.timeout.ms + 200 ms. Looks like appropriate behavior to me. But I still don't understand why the application sends a failed record to the topic even after exceeding delivery.timeout.ms (+ a few minutes). Do you have any idea why this could happen?

Comment: UPD, I found that when I run Kafka again 5 minutes after exceeding delivery.timeout.ms, message still could come to the topic. But if I start Kafka 10 minutes after exceeding delivery.timeout.ms, *failed message doesn't come to the topic*. I don't see any difference in logs, at least on INFO level.

Comment: Sorry; I am not familiar with `KafkaProducer` internals.

Answer (score 0):

If you are below spring kafka 3.0 ,
This is a possible solution.
Hope this helps

```
                var future = template.send(producerRecordSuccess).completable();
                future.whenComplete((result,ex) -> {
                   if (ex == null){
                       //return 200
                   }
                   else if(ex != null){
                       //return 503
                   }
                });
```

Do not use completable if using spring kafka 3.0+ . The default return of template.send() is a CompletableFuture with 3.0+

So your code will be like

```
                var future = template.send(producerRecordSuccess);
                future.whenComplete((result,ex) -> {
                   if (ex == null){
                       //return 200
                   }
                   else if(ex != null){
                       //return 503
                   }
                });
```